# error in getting HTML tag's content using HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to get html content of an html tag using HtmlUnitDriver. The code i have written is:

```
WebElement table_element = wd.findElement(By.id("genericTableFormtable"));
String str=table_element.getAttribute("outerHTML");
int index=str.indexOf("active");
```

If I use ChromeDriver then i get the code in the str, but if I use HtmlUnitDriver then I get an exception in my further code as str is null. Please tell why this is happening

Comment: I suspect that there is no attribute outerHTML when you use the rendering engine HtmlUnitDriver. Why do you need outerHTML?

Comment: i need a part of html code that's why i used outerHTML

Comment: Please add to your question exactly what part from which string you need.

Comment: I have added a new line of code to my question. See I am supposed get table's html code from my first two lines, then i just have to check whether I am having active keyword in that code or not. That's why i need its html code

Answer (score 0):

Try innerHTML instead of outerHTML

```
WebElement table_element = wd.findElement(By.id("genericTableFormtable"));    
String str=table_element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
int index=str.indexOf("active");
```

Also, if active is an attribute, simply get it with getAttribute. To check if a link contains the attribute active, you could do something like this:

```
List<WebElement> table_links = wd.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
foreach(WebElement table_link in table_links){
    if(table_link.getAttribute("active") != null){
         // this link is active
    }
}
```

Or just with indexof:

```
List<WebElement> table_links = wd.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
foreach(WebElement table_link in table_links){
    if(table_link.getAttribute("innerHTML").indexOf("active") > -1){
         // this link is active
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using HtmlUnitDriver. String str=table_element.getAttribute("innerHTML");

Comment: I am using HtmlUnitDriver. String str=table_element.getAttribute("innerHTML"). After execution of this line str is null

Comment: Debug and see which attributes are inside table_element.

Comment: why i need to check attributes. You are not getting my point. See table's html code is something like this. 
<table>

Comment: why i need to check attributes. You are not getting my point. See table's html code is something like this. 
<table>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
I want all this html in a string returned by the method. If i use chromedriver then i get it with the same code i have written but if i use HtmlUnitDriver then i get null in the string